# Testing nested $http requests in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some lines of code I can't manage to test. All provided `API` methods are wrappers around `$http`. `API.getAll` returns me a basic information about panels and `API.getPanel` returns full information about each requested panel. So this kind of loop will exist anyway.

I'm wondering how can I test those nested requests. This is my draft test which doesn't work:

```
describe('static', function() {
    describe('method `getAll`', function() {
        ...
        beforeEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.whenPOST(url, getPanelsForCategory)
                .respond(mockPanelsForCategory);
            $httpBackend.whenPOST(url, getPanelDetails)
                .respond(mockPanel);
        });

        it('should work... Please...', function() {                
            $httpBackend.expectPOST(url, getPanelsForCategory);

            Panel.getAll(1).then(function(panels) {
                // Here everything falls down.
            });

            $httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
});
```

And this is a source code I want to test:

```
    Panel.get = function(id) {
        return API.getPanel(id).then(function(panel) {
            return new Panel(panel);
        });
    };

    Panel.getAll = function(id) {
        var handleResponse = function(data) {
            var promise = $q.all(
                data.map(function(panelRaw) {
                    var panel = Panel.get(panelRaw.PANEL_ID);
                    return panel;
                })
            );

            return promise;
        };

        return API.getPanelsForCategory(id).then(handleResponse);
    };
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `Panel.getAll('category', 1)` at your test to be `Panel.getAll(1)` to be consistent with your implementation?

Another thing. Is there a reason why you haven't mocked `API.getPanel`? Both `Panel.get` and `Panel.getAll` (through `Panel.get`) depend on that.

Comment: I supposed that I can just provide a sample answer through the `$httpBackend` and even didn't think about mocking `API` service. But everything points me to do this.

Comment: Not sure. You probably have to get something simple to work first and consider simplifying your API somehow. Sometimes it makes sense to extract things as parameters and so on.